# Can you specify a directory to compile when running sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to compile a project that is in `/path/to/project`. I can't do `sbt compile /path/to/project`.

How do I achieve this if I can't `cd` into `/path/to/project`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional source directory by adding the following in your **build.sbt**:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += "path/to/directory"
```

You can refer this for additional info :
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html